# How to change fill / shade of ggplot2 plot to use/look like Semiotic

Tags: r, reactjs, d3.js, ggplot2, semiotic

Say that I have this plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Is it possible to change the shading of the bars to be like these plots, which were created using Semiotic:

[image]

The source is: https://medium.com/data-visualization-society/you-can-design-a-good-chart-with-r-5d00ed7dd18e.

Is it possible to somehow combining `ggplot2` with the shading/fill ability of `Semiotic`?